# How to replace an entire ASP control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display a lot of data in a `Table` control, but put the code in a library method that returns a `new Table` object. When I assign that object directly to the control on the ASP page, the data does not show.

The library method looks like this:

```
public Table CreateTable(...)
{
   Table tbl = new Table();
   ...
   // adding lots of cells and setting lots of properties
   ...
   return tbl;
}
```

The ASP page has a `Table` control:

```
<asp:Content ID= ... >
    <asp:Table ID="Table_Data" runat="server">
    </asp:Table>
</asp:Content>
```

In Code-Behind the Table control is assigned the new `Table` object:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table_Data = Lib.CreateTable(...);
}
```

but when tested the Table control shows empty.

This principle has worked by this:

```
Table NewTable = Lib.CreateTable(...);
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(NewTable);
```

but it seems that having a PlaceHolder in my asp page should not be needed.
Or is it?

Any help is appreciated!

---

Update:

The solution is, as the Accepted Answer, to keep the PlaceHolder, but not `<asp:Content>` but a new PlaceHolder control at the exact place where I want the table:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder_Table" runat="server">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and in Code Behind:

```
PlaceHolder_Table.Controls.Add(Lib.CreateTable(...));
```

Simple, and works great.

Comment: We can't debug this, you need to do that. Does `Lib.CreateTable()` actually return anything useful?

Comment: The lib method works perfectly. But I guess that directly replacing a control isn't that obvious. I read something about `Render` calls, but that was about entire pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Content ID="contId" >
    <asp:Table ID="Table_Data" runat="server">
    </asp:Table>
</asp:Content>

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contId.Controls.Clear();
    contId.Controls.Add(Lib.CreateTable(...));
}
```

Comment: I just read somewhere that I can add a placeholder at any place on the page, so that is a terrific solution! Simpler than I feared.

Comment: oh dear, how I (do not) love these code-snippets where you can *run* server-code ...

Answer (score -1):

The asp.net table control isn't supposed to work like this. You're most likely looking for the GridView control, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s019wc0(v=vs.140).aspx). This is used for getting data, binding it to the Gridview and displaying it

The asp.net table control info is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0ce8sc(v=vs.140).aspx). It's more of a format thing rather than using for loads of data, that's why you can't databind to it.